# How can I add to list In Dart

Tags: dart

**Help me to add to the list** 
my code:

```dart
List<Map> = [{'a':1}];
```

I tried `List.add();` but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First give a name to list 
you can use the below code:

```
final List<Map> mylist = [{'a':1}];
mylist.add({'b':2});
print(mylist);
```

try this